# Replace [URL] and [TITLE] with current url and title

Tags: javascript, php, html, svg

I have my mata tags at the top of each page:

```
<meta property="url" content="http://stackoverflow.com" />
<meta property="title" content="MY PAGE" />
```

I have multiple social media svgs I want to link to the current url and title. I have the correct queries for them but I want to add the url and title in dynamically. So Facebook looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]&title=[TITLE]"><img src="images/logo/facebook.svg"></a>
```

I think this can be done by Javascript/PHP but whats the best way?

Comment: How are the meta tags being rendered? Did you write them into a static HTML file? Is PHP generating them?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, this can be done with either PHP OR JavaScript.

## PHP Method

One method of doing this in PHP would be to create a $title and $url variable for each page:

```
<head>
<?php
    $metaUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    $metaTitle = "MY PAGE";
?>
```

And refer them in your meta tags and anchor (note that I am using quick echo notation for echoing the PHP variables, this won't work on older PHP versions where full notation must be used):

```
<meta property="url" content="<?=$metaUrl?>" />
<meta property="title" content="<?=$metaTitle?>" />
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?=$metaUrl?>&title=<?=$metaTitle?>">
        <img src="images/logo/facebook.svg">
    </a>
</body>
```

## JavaScript Method

There is a simple way of doing this via JavaScript as well.  First give your anchor an ID so we can easily find it in the DOM:

```
<a id="fb-sharer" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]&title=[TITLE]"><img src="images/logo/facebook.svg"></a>
```

Now in your script, get the title and url via the DOM document object:

```
var title = document.title;
var url = document.URL;
```

Find your anchor in the DOM and set the href value with the variables:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("fb-sharer");
var link = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + url 
           + "&title=" + title;
anchor.setAttribute("href", link);
```

You can also use JavaScript to write the entire element in one go, throw this where ever your anchor should be:

```
<script>
    var title = document.title;
    var url = document.URL;
    document.write('<a id="fb-sharer"'
                  + 'href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="' + url 
                  + '&title=' + title 
                  + '><img src="images/logo/facebook.svg"></a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript method works great thanks! I couldn't get the PHP method to work just copying as is (confirmed PHP is running with an echo test) but I think that's probably just my lack of PHP knowledge at present and will come back to it later. Thanks!!!

Comment: @StuartDurning it is possible that you cannot use quick echo's because of your PHP version.  If this is the case, then instead of using `<?= $metaUrl ?>` you would have to use `<?php echo $metaUrl; ?>`.  If this doesn't work, I'll have to test it again.